# Make array of all GET-variables

Tags: php, arrays, get

I'm trying to make an array from all the GET-variables passed to a PHP script. So far I haven't found any way to do this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

It's already there by default:

```
print_r($_GET);  // for all GET variables
print_r($_POST); // for all POST variables
```

[PHP docs on all available superglobals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Comment: How would you use a foreach-loop to print key and value of an array (like `$_GET`)?

Comment: @Emil `foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) echo "Key: $key Val: $value<br>";`

Answer (score 19):

There is a [`$_GET`](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_get.asp) super global array to get all variables from query string.

```
// print all contents of $_GET array
print_r($_GET);

// print specific variable
echo $_GET['key_here'];
```

You can also use `foreach` loop to go through all of them like this:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
   echo 'Key = ' . $key . '<br />';
   echo 'Value= ' . $value;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

GET variables are allready passed as an array

Answer (score 4):

The $_REQUEST variable is:

> An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

That could help

Answer (score 4):

```
extract($_REQUEST);
```

Will get every variable passed by post or get and make into a new variable

Answer (score 4):

Get all GET params by :

> $all_params = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']